# How to get time between two specific time period

Tags: php, datetime

What I am doing is actually iterating from 8AM to 9PM with 1 hour interval but it doesn't give me correct result. This is my code below

```
<?php 
    $date = date("08:00");
    for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
    {
        $date = strtotime("+".$i." hour");
        echo date('H:i A', $date);
    }
?>
```

it starts with current time!, 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you sure that you can use date() like this ? I mean what is the value of $date with date("08:00");?

Comment: First argument of date is not time, it's format. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different problems to unpack here:

```
$date = date("08:00");
```

This isn't useful. `date` is for formatting a timestamp - you can't use it to create one from an hours:minutes string like this.

What you probably want is

```
$date = strtotime("08:00");
```

The reason this didn't cause any problems is that inside your loop you then immediately overwrite it with:

```
$date = strtotime("+".$i." hour");
```

This **will** create a new timestamp, but it will be relative to **now**, not your initial time. Saying "+1 hour" means you want a timestamp that is `now + 1 hour`. You can use `strtotime` to create a timestamp relative to another by using the second argument...

```
$date = strtotime("+{$i} hour", $date);
```

...but you're still overwriting your start value. So let's put that in a variable called `$start` instead:

```
$start = strtotime("08:00");
...
$date = strtotime("+".$i." hour", $start);
```

This gets you:

```
<?php 
$start = strtotime("08:00");

for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++) {
  $date = strtotime("+{$i} hour", $start);
  echo date('H:i A', $date), PHP_EOL;
}
```

which will output:

```
08:00 AM
09:00 AM
10:00 AM
...
18:00 PM
```

It doesn't quite get you to 9PM, because that's not ten hours away from 8am, but 13. I'll leave the last part to you.

See https://eval.in/867974

Also, you might want to look at [PHP's DateTime library](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), which gives you an object-oriented interface for working with dates & times. For a simple script like this, it's not vital.